# How to automatically Update/sync ListView UI with change in DB collection in Appcelerator?

Tags: collections, model, appcelerator

I have a ListView that gets FAQ data from a sql table (after it has been downloaded from a server into the DB). The FAQ data is downloaded and correctly saved in the database (savedFAQs below shows the correct, updated FAQs when there was a change on the server), but the ListView UI does not show the changes. The correct, updated FAQs only show up in the ListView when the app restarts.

How can the Listview **automatically** be updated when the user refreshes/reloads?

faqs.xml

```
<Collection src="faqCollection" instance="true" id="faqData"/>
.
.

<ListView id="faqListView" defaultItemTemplate="plainTemplate">
    <RefreshControl id="refresh" onRefreshstart="reloadFAQs" platform="ios"/>
    <Templates>
        <ItemTemplate name="plainTemplate" id="plainTemplate">
            <View width="98%" class="listViewRow">
                <Label bindId="title" id="title"/>
            </View>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </Templates>
    <ListSection id="faqListSection" dataCollection="$.faqData" >
        <ListItem title:text="{faq_title}" nid:itemId="{faq_nid}" mainText:text="{faq_text}" template="{template}"/>
    </ListSection>  
</ListView>
```

faqs.js

```
function autoSaveFAQs(faqs){
 $.faqData.deleteAll();
 console.log("faqs in autosave: " + JSON.stringify(faqs));
 var f;
 _.each(faqs, function(faq){
        faq.time = now; //adds the timestamp when FAQs have been downloaded
        f = Alloy.createModel('faqCollection', faq, {silent: true}); 
        $.faqData.add(f);
        f.save();
 });
 var savedFAQs = $.faqData;
 savedFAQs.fetch();
 console.log("savedFAQs: " + JSON.stringify(savedFAQs)); //shows the updated FAQs when reloaded, but the listview is not populated
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

There was a $.destroy() method too much when the data was fetched:

```
$.faqData.on('fetch', function() {
if (OS_IOS) { 
 $.refresh.endRefreshing(); //only works on Android with AppC SDK 6.2
}
//  $.destroy(); //too much cleaning. updates automatically when not destroyed after refreshEnd
});
```